# Offscreen rendered texture renders empty rectangle on screen

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures, render-to-texture, opengl-es-1.1

I'm trying to create OpenGL ES 1.1 texture and fill is with rendered content.

Preparing a texture:

```
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 32, 32, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

GLuint texFrambuffer;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &texFrambuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, texFrambuffer);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);

GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) ;
if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", status);
    // this message doesn't appear, thus, framebuffer is complete
}

glViewport(0, 0, 32, 32);

glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

GLfloat vertices[] = {
    10.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f,
    20.0f, 40.0f, 0.0f,
    10.0f, 30.0f, 0.0f
};
glColor4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 3);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &texFrambuffer);
```

Rendering texture into scene:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
GLshort texCoord[] = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1};
GLfloat vertices2[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 31.0f, 31.0f, 0.0f, 31.0f, 31.0f};
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices2);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_SHORT, 0, texCoord);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Full source code is available at Bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/amjaliks/gl2/src/66ee4932e212/GL2/GL2View.m

There other content is rendered correctly. Issue is only with this texture – it renders as a white rectangle.

I have studied a lot of example, but still can't figure out what I doing wrong. What is missing?

---

**Update 1:** I have noticed, if I set `glClearColor()` and call `glClear()` while `texFrambuffer` is bound, these changes is saved to my texture. Thus, there is something wrong with `glDrawArrays()` and/or related things.

Do I need set matrix mode and projection specifically for my `texFrambuffer`?

---

**Update 2:** I have tried also to use `glCopyTexImage2D` to copy content from "main" framebuffer to a texture.

```
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 32, 32, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

glViewport(0, 0, 32, 32);

glClearColor(1.0f, 0.75f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    20.0f, 32.0f, 0.0f,
    10.0f, 30.0f, 0.0f
};
glColor4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 3);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glCopyTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 0, 0, 32, 32, 0);
```

Full source code available at Bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/amjaliks/gl2/src/b3339661650e/GL2/GL2View.m

The result is the same. Only filled rectangle. It looks like there is definitely issue with my matrices.

Comment: Shoudln't you be using glGenFramebuffersOES, glBindFramebufferOES, and so on... OES functions, instead of core? Because ES 1.1 doesn't have Framebuffer objects in core, they are available as extension.

Comment: It seems Apple has merged APIs. There is no difference to use methods with OES and without OES.

Comment: What do you mean - merged? It's written even in Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESontheiPhone/OpenGLESontheiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH101-SW6 (Framebuffer Objects are the Only Rendering Target on iOS) That on GLES 1.1 you should be using OES_framebuffer_object extension.

Comment: @MārtiņšMožeiko I have just tried to fix my example, by using OES methods. There is no difference in result at all. Even more, I have added `glClearColor()` and `glClear()` calls, while `texFramebuffer` is bound. Now I get texture filled with this colour. Thus, FBOs works fine (even without OES). But I still missing triangle drawn by `glDrawArrays()`.

Comment: @MārtiņšMožeiko Here is code all with OES functions. Still no desired result: https://bitbucket.org/amjaliks/gl2/src/328701fcd2f7/GL2/GL2View.m :(

Comment: Ok, then your problem is with matrices. By default projection matrix is identity. Thus giving (-1,-1)-(+1,+1) coordinates for viewport. Most likely you need orthographic projection to (0,0)-(32,32) square.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8478/discussion-between-aleksejs-mjaliks-and-mrtis-mozeiko)

Comment: @MartinsMozeiko Wouldn't you like to add your comment about matrices as answer? You were right, I have need to set up `glOrtho`. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with matrices. By default projection matrix is identity. Thus giving (-1,-1)-(+1,+1) coordinates for viewport. Most likely you need orthographic projection to (0,0)-(32,32) square.